# Why does my Python Dataflow job gets stuck at the Write phase?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I wrote a Python Dataflow job which managed to process 300 files, unfortunately, when I try to run it on 400 files it gets stuck in the Write phase forever.

The logs aren't really helpful, but I think that the issue comes from the writing logic of the code, initially, I only wanted 1 output file, so I wrote:

```
     | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(
                known_args.output,
                file_name_suffix=".json",
                num_shards=1,
                shard_name_template=""
            ))
```

Then, I removed,  `num_shards=1` and `shard_name_template=""` and I was able to process more files but it'd still get stuck.

**Extra Information**

- the files to process are small, less than a 1MB
- also, when removing the num_shards and shard_name_template fields, I noticed that the data got output a temporary folder in the target path, but the job never finishes
- I have the following `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` exception and I tried solving it by increasing  --num_workers to 6 and --disk_size_gb to 30 but it doesn't work.

```
Error message from worker: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 638, in do_work work_executor.execute() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 179, in execute op.start() File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 63, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 64, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 79, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 80, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 82, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/shuffle.py", line 441, in __iter__ for entry in entries_iterator: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/shuffle.py", line 282, in __next__ return next(self.iterator) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/shuffle.py", line 240, in __iter__ chunk, next_position = self.reader.Read(start_position, end_position) File "third_party/windmill/shuffle/python/shuffle_client.pyx", line 133, in shuffle_client.PyShuffleReader.Read OSError: Shuffle read failed: b'DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: (g)RPC timed out when extract-fields-three-mont-10090801-dlaj-harness-fj4v talking to extract-fields-three-mont-10090801-dlaj-harness-1f7r:12346. Server unresponsive (ping error: Deadline Exceeded, {"created":"@1602260204.931126454","description":"Deadline Exceeded","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/deadline/deadline_filter.cc","file_line":69,"grpc_status":4}). Typically one can self manage this issue, please read: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#tsg-rpc-timeout'
```

Can you please recommend ways to troubleshoot this type of issues?

Comment: In the Dataflow Monitoring UI are you still seeing activity on the worker ( job metrics ) when things are stuck? If yes then things are still writing but taking a long time. 

If the later, (with the num_shards value not set) are you seeing the Autoscaler making requests to increase the number of hosts?

Also what is the volume of data being processed ? Are these lots of small files or lots of very large files.

Comment: thanks @RezaRokni I've updated my question by answering you in the extra information section. I see the activity of the data processed going to 0, and the job fails by timing out.

Comment: Just to check its the write phase, run the job with no write output. This will ensure that its not something to do with the data, which shows up when running with all the files. For example I have seen regex statements that never return.

If the above passes, then it maybe that the processing is causing a very large fan out of data which then needs to be shuffled. You may also want to look at enabling the shuffle service for Dataflow. Please note that this has a cost associated based on the amount of data shuffled.

Answer (score 1):

After trying to pump resources, I managed to get it working by enabling the Dataflow shuffle service fixed the situation. Please see [resource](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-shuffle)

Just add `--experiments=shuffle_mode=service` to your `PipelineOptions`.